# Aspx replace strings

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

how can I replace some strings in asp (.aspx and .master)

```
<a href="/<%#Eval ("Link") %>" >My link</a>
```

I want to replace some things from "Link"

thanks!

Comment: Replace them in what way?  Do you mean replace them in the markup using Visual Studio (find and replace), or replace them during runtime?

Comment: during runtime. I get the "link" from the database, and for example I want to replace in
"{hello}/asd/dsa"
"{hello}" = "byebye"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Link").ToString().Replace(...)%>`

Comment: mmm I get this error
CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Replace' and no extension method 'Replace' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: try adding tostring - updated answer (sorry, i dont use asp.net webforms anymore, im into mvc now)